# AdMob still not working

Tags: android, admob

I got a problem regarding Google AdMob:

I try to display a Interstitial, for this I have added the AdActivity, permissions and meta-tags to manifest.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.lunation.warface"
android:versionCode="10"
android:versionName="1.4" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"   />
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" >

    <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
            </action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="gallery.FullScreenViewActivity"></activity>





    </application>

</manifest>
```

In MainActivity:

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("xxx/xxx");

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
     mInterstitialAd.show();
}
```

Logcat:

```
04-04 15:15:19.397: W/Ads(19752): There was a problem getting an ad         response. ErrorCode: 0
 04-04 15:15:19.407: I/dalvikvm(19752): Could not find method      android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method      com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.s.g.<init>
04-04 15:15:19.407: W/dalvikvm(19752): VFY: unable to resolve  virtual     method 3153: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setMixedContentMode  (I)V
04-04 15:15:19.407: D/dalvikvm(19752): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x004a

04-04 15:15:19.502: W/Ads(19752): Failed to load ad: 0
```

Besides there is also a compilation error:

**Conversion of dalvik format failed with error code 1**

I tried about 20 answers, still not working.

I also dont know whether the problem is the unit id, I can change

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("xxx/xxx");
```

to:

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("xxx");
```

and I got the same errors.

I use the following external libraries:
android support v4&v7, picasso, ftpclient(commons, httpmime),FAB

Does somebody have a advice?

Greetings

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: I have Eclipse, so I dont have a build.gradle file ):

Comment: Well, then it will be even more difficult. Besides the "failed to load ad error", how could you get compilation error. The latter would prevent you from running the app.

Comment: I only cannot export signed application during the admob library is added. If i remove it, everything works fine....weird..

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!

Seems like some features in CyanogenMod blocks AdMob.
Flashed a new version WITHOUT Adaware and blocking Tools.

WORKING NOW :D